# Cookies secure and httpOnly with React and Cookie-Storage

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, react-redux

I'm trying to put secure and httpOnly in my cookie, but it doesn't recognize it:

```js
     import { CookieStorage } from 'cookie-storage';

        const KEY_SECURE = 'cookie-secure';

        const store = new CookieStorage({
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            sameSite: 'strict',
        });

        export default class AuthToken {
            static getToken() {
                return JSON.parse(store.getItem(KEY_SECURE)) || null;
            }
            static setToken(token) {
                if (token) {
                    store.setItem(KEY_SECURE, JSON.stringify(token));
                    AuthToken.setSesion();
                } else {store.removeItem(KEY_SECURE);
                    AuthToken.removeSesion();
                    AuthToken.removeLastUserEvent();
                }
            }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What sets the token variable? It looks like it'll always return false from the snippet.

Comment: `
static getAuthorization() {
        const token = AuthToken.getToken();
        return `${token.type} ${token.value}`;
    }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because I executed it in an unsafe environment HTTP, in HTTPS works fine.